# What is the correspondence between application, process, and Java virtual machine?

Tags: java, android, operating-system, jvm

In Android, we can use `android:process` attribute to specify a process for the `<activity>` component. So what is the correspondence between application, process, and Java virtual machine? And is there any difference between common Java application and Android application about this question?

Answer (score 0):

The Java of Android is an implementation of the Java language (which is just a standard) but it doesn't use the JVM (which is another implementation of the Java language).

Android actually compiles Java to a different bytecode and interprets this other bytecode at runtime using the ART (Android Runtime).

The "Java" of Android is completely different than the actual Java.

> So what is the correspondence between application, process, and Java virtual machine?

Android is a fancy Linux distribution for smartphones. It is like Ubuntu for smartphones. Instead of using pre-existing desktop environments, Google wrote their own targeting smartphones and tablets. Ubuntu is just a fancy package manager. You can make your own Ubuntu in 5 hours. It is called Linux From Scratch (LFS).

The Java virtual machine is probably written in C or C++. It makes system calls just like any other C program out there. It is really nothing fancy. Just a very big software which interprets bytecode and translates it to actual syscalls.